# Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer : BSONTypeError

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

```js
router.get('/editProduct/:id', async(req,res) => {
  let products = await productHelpers.findProduct(req.params.id);
  console.log(products);
  res.render('admin/editProduct');
});
```

**findProduct function is given below:**

```js
findProduct:(proId) => {
  return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
    db
      .get()
      .collection(collection.PRODUCT_COLLECTION)
      .findOne({_id:objectId(proId)})
      .then((products) => {
        resolve(products)
      })
  })
}
```

**My problem is I cannot render the `editProduct` page**. `Products` are printed on the console, so there is no problem with the `findProduct` function.

When I render a page it shows an error in terminal as follows:

[image: Error details]

I can redirect a page but cannot render a page in this case.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Does your document in MongoDB, the `_id` is ObjectId type? Does `req.params.id` is a valid ObjectId string?

Comment: Actually I am getting products using that function. But my problem is I cannot render a page after resolving products. But I can Redirect to a page. Pls check the question

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the *additional* resources (images, Javascript) that your page `/admin/editProduct/<id>` loads after successfully finding a product. The log shows many such requests, like `GET /admin/editProduct/js/main.js`, and they all fail with 404 Not Found. I assume you have an `express.static(...)` route that is meant to serve them, can you share that?

The BSONTypeError that you observe would be explained if one of these additional resources had the form `GET /admin/editProduct/style.css`. Such a request would be matched by the `/editProduct/:id` route, because it has only one `/` after the `editProduct`. Inside that route, you would then have `req.params.id = "style.css"`, which is not a valid ObjectId string.

Comment: If this is truly the case, this is a gem of an answer.